# Если не тянет ни file_get_contents ни curl ?

Tags: curl, php

Попробовал через curl... и снова ответ пуст(

```
<?php
ob_start();
$ch = curl_init("http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=91100&xhr=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.1.1");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if( !$result ) $error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// $content можно грабить (// я по старинке )

$fromBodyToBody = substr($content, strpos($content, '<body>')+6);
$fromBodyToBody = substr($fromBodyToBody, 0, strpos($fromBodyToBody, '</body>'));

// вот контент между <body> и </body>
echo $fromBodyToBody;
?>
```

Другие сайты берет, а этот нет. Подскажите как с него таки вытянуть инфу?

Comment: я незнаю что там и как у вас, у меня через file_get_contents тянет на ура

Comment: с денвера у меня тоже тянет, а вот с хостинга выдаёт пустоту...

Сначала тянул а вчера почему то перестал...

Comment: А на чем обрубается - таймаут?

Comment: Не пронятно... просто ничего не выводит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой контент в переменной $result, просто убери функции буферизации вывода

Comment: Помогло, только не $result, а $content )